# NgClick functions, events and expressions

Tags: angularjs, tags, click

I would just like to ask if ng-click can handle two different tasks such us loading an iframe on click and changing the specific image to another image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by that you mean call two functions after a single click, the answer is yes, you can. In the 'ng-click' attribute, you can add in multiple functions to be called in sequence. Separate each function by a semi-colon.

```
<!-- Assumes these functions are defined in your controller -->
<button ng-click="loadFrame();changeImage();"></button>
```